# In a "One to Many" relation.. i want to delete one degree from a CV I get a "Transaction rolled back " exception

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, ejb-3.0

In a "One to Many" relation between these classes (CV and degrees).
my scenario: a CV has 3 degrees..when i want to delete one degree from a CV I get a "Transaction rolled back " exception..

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`consoftcv/cv_degrees`, CONSTRAINT `FKA278F3B18D2CAE7` FOREIGN KEY (`degrees_DegreeId`) REFERENCES `degrees` (`DegreeId`))

```
public void delete(Degrees e) 
{ 
   e = em.find(Degrees.class, e.getDegreeId()); 
   if (e != null) 
     em.remove(e); 
}
```

I'm using  hibernate,EJB..is there an annotation??
thx

Comment: It sounds like you delete the degree, without removing the reference from the CV first.  let's see the code you use to delete.

Comment: yes..  public void delete(Degrees e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  e = em.find(Degrees.class, e.getDegreeId());
  if (e != null)
   em.remove(e);
 }

Comment: am i supposed to delete the reference before in the middle table??!! i think it's automatically done..any way shall I delete it manualy in case there is no annotation by JPA or hibernate.. thx

Comment: Hibernate should take care of the cascade if you configured it. Can you show your configuration for Degree and CV?

Comment: @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.REMOVE})
 @IndexColumn(name = "dg")
 private List<Degrees> degrees;   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 private CV cv;

Comment: i used @indexColumn because there is a repetitive when calling cv.Tostring...

Comment: Edit your question when you add code - it's hard to read it in comment form.

Comment: sorry i'm not used to use stackoverflow